# How can I debug Ginkgo tests in VS Code?

Tags: go, debugging, visual-studio-code, ginkgo

I'm evaluating `ginkgo` at the moment - I very much like the BDD style.

However I'm unable at the moment to get the VS Code debugger to work with the framework. The official VS-Code extension provides test-by-test debugging for native go tests using CodeLens. With other languages and frameworks (eg Typescript/Mocha), I've been able to debug individual test files by setting up `launch.json` appropriately, but have been unable to find suitable examples for `go`.

Does anybody have any examples of any `launch.json` setups for debugging `ginkgo` tests (or go code invoked from any other framework)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After a bit of playing around I found a way forward which perhaps should have been obvious. In case it isn't I'll leave the question and this answer here:

For a package `foo`, a `foo_suite_test.go` file is generated by the `gingko bootstrap` command. This contains a top-level test called `TestFoo` which runs the rest of the tests within the package.

This *does* have a CodeLens `run test | debug test` section above it which you can use to debug the entire suite.

[image: CodeLens screenshot]

It's not *quite* as convenient as the individual CodeLens entries which appear over *each* native go test, but it's easy enough to isolate specific tests to run using the Gingko `F` prefix.

Comment: Thanks, you just made this so much easier, I've been banging my head against this for a while :)

Comment: How can I invoke this from the command palette, so I can program a macro key for it?

Comment: @TheDiveO not sure you can directly invoke from command pallette but you can get the `go test` command by clicking on 'run test' and looking at the output pane. Then set up a debug task for it in `launch.json`. Then you'll be able to invoke directly from the debug menu.

Comment: that's an idea, but this begs the question how to launch the correct task unambiguously...

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth raising a specific question on this?

Answer (score 0):

Tried out by creating launch.json , but not work for me , I  Used bellow code to filter out the test case and used normal debug functionality .

```
func TestEnd2End(t *testing.T) {
format.MaxLength = 0
RegisterFailHandler(Fail)
suiteConfig, reporterConfig := GinkgoConfiguration()
suiteConfig.LabelFilter = "DEBUG"
suiteConfig.FocusStrings = []string{"sample"}
RunSpecs(t, "End2End Suite", suiteConfig, reporterConfig)}
```

Note :suiteConfig is used to filter out . Not convenient way but work for me .